# How to convert human-readable date string back into time

Tags: php, string, date

My website uses the following code:

```
$a1="1293011062"; // hex code umm i think !
$expires = date('M d, Y', $a1);
echo $expires; // Output Dec 22, 2010
```

How can I do the reverse operation? That is, what if i want to convert `Apr 06, 2012` to hex, the way it's represented in `a1`?

Comment: It's the number of seconds elapsed since Jan. 1 1970 (A.K.A. UNIX timestamp), not a "hex code.

Comment: @VincentSavard Ooh ! really ! i thought it is some kind of encryption ~thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strtotime: https://www.php.net/strtotime and that isn't hex

```
<?php
$a1="1293004800";
$expires = date('M d, Y', $a1);
echo $expires . "<br/>"; // Output Dec 22, 2010

echo strtotime($expires); // 1293004800
?>
```